# Django - KeyError at /auctions/create 'category.' (New to Django, any help is appreciated!)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am new to Django and creating a dropdown menu so that users can choose a category from the dropdown. This category will be saved on an entry on the website, when a user creates a new entry. I migrated the model, but I'm getting: KeyError at /auctions/create
'category.' Any help is really appreciated.

Views.py (Code for creating the dropdown menu for categories)

[image: views.py]

models.py

[image: models.py]

forms.py

[image: forms.py]

Here is the create part in views.py for creating a new entry. 'form' for CreateForm() is the model form for creating the entry. 'form1' for CategoryForm() is the model form for the category drop down list. The create function was working completely fine, until I added in the parts for the categories and category form.

[image: create]

urls.py for applicable functions (I have tried many variations for the category one but I'm still having trouble figuring out what it should be, I have tried str and int.)
Sorry I'm a beginner but any help would be great!

```
path("auctions/create", views.create, name="create"),
path("listings/<int:id>", views.listingpage, name="listingpage"),
path("cat/<int:id>", views.cat, name="cat"),
```

Answer (score 0):

A Python `KeyError` exception is what is raised when you try to access a key that isn’t in a dictionary,and I think your error is probably coming from here

```
categoryCreated = categories.objects.create(category=category)
```

and you should write your model name `Categories` for a good practice not `categories`

Comment: Thanks, I actually found the problem just now - I had if form1.is_valid(): but then the next line said category = form instead of category = form1. So that was my mistake! I also read up more on the model names and changed mine to upper case, thanks for the tip.